# hyperledger composer deploy example code fails

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Currently working with the latest releases of the hyperledger development environment and am working through the admin services. The example code for admin -> deploy is documented as:

```
// Deploy a Business Network Definition
var adminConnection = new AdminConnection();
var businessNetworkDefinition = BusinessNetworkDefinition.fromArchive(myArchive);
return adminConnection.deploy(businessNetworkDefinition)
.then(function(){
    // Business network definition deployed
})
.catch(function(error){
    // Add optional error handling here.
});
```

In the code as provided, the second line fails as `BusinessNetworkDefinition` is not a part of the composer-admin node module. I have two options for creating a BusinessNetworkDefinition, one is to use composer-client. This fails with the following message: `TypeError: composerClient.BusinessNetworkDefinition is not a constructor`
The code used for this attempt is summarized here:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var composer = require('composer-admin');
var composerClient = require('composer-client');
var composerCommon = require('composer-common');

    var businessNetworkDefinition = new composerClient.BusinessNetworkDefinition();
```

The other option is to use composer-common, which fails with the following message: `TypeError: businessNetworkDefinition.fromArchive is not a function`
The code used for this attempt is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var composer = require('composer-admin');
var composerClient = require('composer-client');
var composerCommon = require('composer-common');

    var net_identifier = "zerotoblockchain-network@0.1.6";
    var net_description = "Z2B network";
    var net_package = require("../../../../network/package.json");
    var net_readme = "../../../../README.md";

    var businessNetworkDefinition = new composerCommon.BusinessNetworkDefinition(net_identifier, net_description, net_package, net_readme);
    var archive = businessNetworkDefinition.fromArchive(req.body.myArchive);
```

where `req.body.myArchive` is the name of the archive file to be used in the fromArchive method. Inspecting the BusinessNetworkDefinition created via the `new` command shows the following:

```
object property: modelManager
object property: aclManager
object property: queryManager
object property: scriptManager
object property: introspector
object property: factory
object property: serializer
object property: metadata
```

So, two questions:

- One: What was created with the `new` command and
- Two: How do I correctly create a `BusinessNetworkDefinition` object which as a `fromArchive()` function in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code in the hyperledger composer documentation is flawed. Following is code which will successfully execute a business network deploy. 
(1) Required definitions:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
let composerAdmin = require('composer-admin');
const BusinessNetworkDefinition = require('composer-common').BusinessNetworkDefinition;
```

The following is written as an exportable, routable routine in nodejs and has been tested through from client (browser). Client passes in name of network to deploy. File layout is:

```
root/network/dist/network-archive-file.bna
```

(2) Read in the archive file and create an admin connection:

```
/**
 * Deploys a new BusinessNetworkDefinition to the Hyperledger Fabric. The connection must be connected for this method to succeed.
 * @param {express.req} req - the inbound request object from the client
 *  req.body.myArchive: _string - string name of object
 *  req.body.deployOptions: _object - string name of object
 * @param {express.res} res - the outbound response object for communicating back to client
 * @param {express.next} next - an express service to enable post processing prior to responding to the client
 * returns composerAdmin.connection - either an error or a connection object
 * @function
 */
exports.deploy = function(req, res, next) {

    let newFile = path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename),'network/dist',req.body.myArchive);
    let archiveFile = fs.readFileSync(newFile);

    let adminConnection = new composerAdmin.AdminConnection();
```

(3) Invoke the (asynchronous) fromArchive function and then deploy the result of the fromArchive invocation.

```
return BusinessNetworkDefinition.fromArchive(archiveFile)
    .then(function(archive) {
        adminConnection.connect(config.composer.connectionProfile, config.composer.adminID, config.composer.adminPW)
        .then(function(){
            adminConnection.deploy(archive)
```

(4). Respond to the (browser based) request:

```
           .then(function(){
                console.log('business network deploy successful: ');
                res.send({deploy: 'succeeded'});
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log('business network deploy failed: ',error);
                res.send({deploy: error});
                });
```

... (5) and for anyone copying all the code, a few closing braces:

```
        });
    });
};
```